# FireFox doesn't send cross-domain ajax?

Tags: ajax, firefox

Here is a problem: when user make authorisation on one server (e.g. a.com) he should be authorised (over jQuery-ajax) on another server (e.g. b.com) - the user-DB is shared for both this sites. Js-code written is

```
var form = jQuery('#auth_form');
var data = form.serialize();
var url = 'http://www.b.com/auth';
jQuery.ajax({
  url: url,
  crossDomain: true,
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'html',
  data: data,
  xhrFields: {
    withCredentials: true
  },
  success: function (html) {
  },
  error: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
  }
});
```

When server send response, he set some of header

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.a.com");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST,GET,OPTION");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, authorization, accept, client-security-token");

It works fine in Chrome and Opera, but ForeFox seems even dousn't send request to server and writes something like this in console log:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://www.b.com. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.
```

FireFox is latest version (37.0.1) and it's written that version 3.5+ supports CORS and i don't understand what is going wrong? I've tried look network through  Fiddler - and i don't see request to b.com from FireFox (from Chrome i see one - everything is Ok). I've tried manage FireFox options `(capability.policy.default.XMLHttpRequest.open = allAccess)`, but it doesn't work. Where is any solution? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You say you are making the request from `a.com` but the server only permits requests from `www.a.com`

Comment: If the request isn't showing up in Fiddler then you probably haven't configured Firefox to use Fiddler (not that there is much point these days, the Net tab in built in developer tools serves 99% of usecases for Fiddler)

Comment: Sorry for a mistake - i mean that in FireFox log-message there is domain a.com (not www.a.com). And Fiddler configured properly as i can see request to a.com, which was sent when form submit, but i don't see request to b.com which must be send via ajax.